# How to get values from BindingSource in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable, sqldataadapter

I am working with `WinForm` in this i have 3 `RadioButton` one `ComboBox` and have three `BindingSource`

I want that when I check any of the `RadioButton`s, the values from the particular `DataSources` get bound to the ComboBox's `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`.
The program has a SQL query where I want to send value based on the checked radio button.

```
private void rdbMed_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbStock.DataSource = null;
    cmbStock.DataSource = this.medicinesBindingSource;
    this.cmbStock.DisplayMember = ""; //i want to bind "Med_ID" from medicinesBindingSource
    this.cmbStock.ValueMember = "";  //"Med_Name"

}

private void rdbCat_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbStock.DataSource = null;
    cmbStock.DataSource = this.categoriesBindingSource;
    this.cmbStock.DisplayMember = ""; //"category_Name"
    this.cmbStock.ValueMember = ""; // category_ID"
}

private void rdbPharm_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbStock.DataSource = null;
    cmbStock.DataSource = this.pharmaceuticalBindingSource;
    this.cmbStock.DisplayMember = "";// "Pharma_Name"
    this.cmbStock.ValueMember = "";// "Pharma_ID"
}
```

Bellow are the parameter of the Query. It will help you to understand what I want to achieve.

```
if (rdbMed.Checked)
{
    con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Med_ID", cmbStock.ValueMember);
    con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_ID", "");
    con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pharma_ID", "");
}
else if (rdbCat.Checked)
{
    con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Med_ID", "");
    con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_ID", cmbStock.ValueMember);
    con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pharma_ID", "");
}
else if (rdbPharm.Checked)
{
    con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Med_ID", "");
    con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_ID", "");
    con.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pharma_ID", cmbStock.ValueMember);
}
```

Comment: You would put your Property names in the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties (what looks like is commented out next to each property).  You use the cmbStock.SelectedValue to retrieve the value then.  Check for null just in case.  Don't leave your connections and commands open like that — put it all in using-blocks so that they're disposed when not in use.

Comment: Yes,Thank you it is working as i was expecting. i was thinking if i put it there ,it will be equal to assigning "Med_ID" or "Med_Name" to DisplayMember or ValueMember.

Comment: DisplayMember is what gets shown on the screen, ValueMember is the data you would care about.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and the least pain way of doing this is resolving it inside SQL command and way to do it is cast your columns with `AS VM` and `AS DM` and make your `DisplayMember = "DM"` and `ValueMember = "VM"`, so if you have sql query like `SELECT USERID AS VM, NAME AS DM` or `SELECT PRODUCTID AS VM, NAME AS DM` it will both work.

Problem later is if you do something with code and you may make mistakes trying to get `USERID` from databinding but it is instead `VM`. To avoid this you could "double select" values in query like `SELECT USERID, NAME, ...., USERID AS VM, NAME AS DM` this way you will have `VM` and `DM` for your controls but still hold original columns.